# In Swift, how do I check if an object is a collection of any type?

Tags: json, swift

I'm working on creating a JSON visualizer (`UIScrollView` with expandable views for each value) and I'm running into an issue:

I've got an `NSDictionary`, returned by `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData`. I want to check the values of it's objects and find out which ones are Arrays or Dictionaries.

Ideally, I'm hoping that Arrays and Dictionaries have an underlying type, such as `Collection` or `Iterable`, so that I don't have to handle them separately. If they don't have that underlying type, how can I check to see if a given `NSDictionary.objectForKey` is a collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this

```
if object is NSDictionary {

} else if object is NSArray {

}
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Ohhh! I was using `object is [NSDictionary]`, there's my problem

Comment: I still wish there was a way to treat these as the same, so I can do operations on each